# How do you turn a pre typed file into parallel arrays and find the largest number in c++?

Tags: c++

for my class we have to take a file that he set and set it into three parallel arrays. Then go through the arrays and find the highest value and output it onto a file.This is what i have written so far.

```
void highScore(string x, string y)
{
const int sizeOfArray = 10;
string name[sizeOfArray];
int idNum[sizeOfArray];
float balance[sizeOfArray];
float highBalance = 0;
int highId = 0;
string highName;

ifstream InFile(x.c_str());
ofstream OFile(y.c_str(), ios::app);

for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    getline(InFile, name[i], '\n');
    InFile >> idNum[i] >> balance[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    if(balance[i] > highBalance)
    {
        highBalance = balance[i];
        highName = name[i];
        highId = idNum[i];
    }
}

OFile << left;
OFile << "Larger Balance:" << endl;
OFile << "ID #     NAME                     BALANCE DUE" << endl;
OFile << "----     --------------------     -----------" << endl;
OFile << setw(9) << highId << setw(25) << highName << "$";
OFile << left;
OFile << setw(10) << highBalance << endl;

}
```

This is the file we take data from.

```
Jean Rousseau
1001 15.50
Steve Woolston
1002 1423.20
Michele Rousseau
1005 52.75
Pete McBride
1007 500.32
Florence Rousseau
1010 1323.33
Lisa Covi
1009 332.35
Don McBride
1003 12.32
Chris Carroll
1008 32.35
Yolanda Agredano
1004 356.00
Sally Sleeper
1006 32.36
```

and the end result is suppost to look like.

```
Larger Balance:
ID # NAME BALANCE DUE
---- -------------------- -----------
1002 Steve Woolston $ 1423.20
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: What is the problem in your code? What is the output you are getting? Whether is it running or not?

Comment: At a glance, I suspect that the input loop is only reading the first half of the file, and every second entry in the array has an empty name and uninitialised numbers.

Comment: The output never puts the right value for id and balance. It also leaves the name blank. How do you think I should fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine.  The only problem I see is your input loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    getline(InFile, name[i], '\n');
    InFile >> idNum[i] >> balance[i];
}
```

Let's lay the file out in bytes (I'll use `\n` for newline):

```
Jean Rousseau\n1001 15.50\nSteve Woolston\n1002 1423.20\n...
```

And now, this is where your file pointer ends up after the first iteration of the loop:

```
Jean Rousseau\n1001 15.50\nSteve Woolston\n1002 1423.20\n...
                         ^--HERE
```

Because the `\n` actually *delimits* numeric input, the character was not removed from the stream.  So, next time around the loop, you call `getline` and this happens:

```
Jean Rousseau\n1001 15.50\nSteve Woolston\n1002 1423.20\n...
                           ^--HERE
```

Whoah, you just read an empty line!  Now, when you try to input two numeric values, it fails because no integer or floating-point value begins with `S`.  But now, you're positioned correctly and so the third time around the loop will work again.

After input, your arrays might look like this:

```
    name                    idNum         balance
0   "Jean Rousseau"         1001          15.5
1   ""                      -17733678     1.5944e-5
2   "Steve Woolston"        1002          1423.2
3   ""                      499911200     7.773883e50            
4   "Michele Rousseau"      1005          52.75
...
etc
```

The problem is that you *assumed* your array at index 1 had valid numbers.  Since input actually failed, those values are *uninitialised*.  They just contain whatever garbage was in memory when your program ran.  So, chances are that one of those will be selected as the highest balance, and that will be paired with the empty name you read.

The easy solution is to skip over the remainder of the line (you should include `<limits>` in your source file).

```
getline(InFile, name[i], '\n');
InFile >> idNum[i] >> balance[i];
InFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Alternatively, you could ensure proper line-based behaviour by using `getline` followed by string streams:

```
getline( InFile, name[i] );
string record;
getline( InFile, record );
istringstream iss( record );
iss >> idNum[i] >> balance[i];
```